# C# (Windows Forms) - Panel with Autoscroll places Generated Object Randomly further away

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, oop, panel

I have a Panel that got the **Autoscroll** enabled.

Now here's my quite interesing annormaly:

If I add One of my Objects `inputForm`to the Panel `panel`the first three to four always get placed the right way.
But if I now pause for like a second with creating the Objects into the Panel the distance between the new created one and the last created one is getting verry high.
I've checked my values but these are ok and work just fine.
My intention is that the Objects are created along the X Axis.

[image: Whats is that distance? Where is it comming from?]

And it should look like this....

[image: Looks better]

As you can see between these two Objects and the next one is too much space.

My Code looks like this:

This Method adds the Object to the Panel.

```
        public void AddInputField(Panel panel)
    {
        panel.VerticalScroll.Enabled = true;
        //New Instance
        inputField inputField = new inputField(this.Index, this.Max);

        //Check if first run
        if (this.Index == 0)
        {
            panel.Controls.Add(inputField.getInputField());
        }
        //do every other run
        else
        {
            this.X = this.X + 170;
            panel.Controls.Add(inputField.getInputField(this.X));
        }
        this.inputFields.Add(inputField);

        //Add One
        this.Index++;
        this.Max++;
    }
```

And here I set the Distance for the next object:

```
        public Panel getInputField(int X)
    {
        this.mainFrame.Location = new Point(X,0);
        return this.mainFrame;
    }
```

And here is how I created the Panel inside my Object class:

```
        //Main Frame
        this.mainFrame = new Panel();
        this.mainFrame.AutoScroll = true;
        this.mainFrame.Name = "MainFrame" + Counter;
        this.mainFrame.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        this.mainFrame.Size = new Size(164,111);
        this.mainFrame.Margin = defaultMargin;
        this.mainFrame.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```

The Class inputField is declared like this:

```
    class inputField
{
```

If you need further Information please let me know.

Comment: is `inputField` inherited from panel? could you please post that class too?

Comment: No, inputField is a class by it's own. Also this class has more than 400 Lines of Code and Comments. I don't think you want to have all of this

Comment: Wouldn't a FlowLayoutPanel make more sense for laying out those duplicate controls?

Comment: @HandbagCrab this sounds interesting. I will try this tomorrow :)

Comment: I don't see the relevant code.  But this is a common mishap, you must correct the control's Location property by the panel's AutoScrollPosition.